# css selector enable only if does not have ancestor div with specific id

Tags: html, css

I'm using pandoc to build up an html, and the way it builds up its table of contents is an unordered list of unordered lists. I'm using a css stylesheet what presents bullets as this long dash, here's a short repro, minimal-ish repro:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 2em;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  margin-bottom: -0.2em;
}

li {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

ul>li:before {
  content: "\2014";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="TOC" role="doc-toc">
  <h1 id="toctitle">Contents</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>1 Intro</li>
    <li>2 Next
      <ul>
        <li>2.1 Sub</li>
        <li>2.2 MoreSub</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3 More</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>Introduction</h1>
Here's another unordered list
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is to *remove* those dashes only from the unordered list items in the table of contents (the bit under `<div id="TOC">`), but keep them for any other unordered list (like the other unordered list in the example). That is, the `ul > li:before` part I want to apply only if this item is not a descendent of the `TOC` div.

`:not(#TOC) > ul > li:before {` works for the outer list but not the inner list, which makes sense to me.

`:not(#TOC) ul > li:before {` seems to have no affect at all.

`:not(div.#TOC) ul > li:before {` somehow disables *all* of the dashes, which I don't understand, since I'd expect the second unordered list to match this.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:not(...)` doesn't work because your non-`TOC` `<ul>` elements don't have non-`<body>` parents. You could target `<ul>` elements that are direct descendants of the `<body>` element, like so:

```
body > ul > li::before {
  content: "\2014";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 2em;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  margin-bottom: -0.2em;
}

li {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

body > ul > li::before {
  content: "\2014";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="TOC" role="doc-toc">
  <h1 id="toctitle">Contents</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>1 Intro</li>
    <li>2 Next
      <ul>
        <li>2.1 Sub</li>
        <li>2.2 MoreSub</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3 More</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>Introduction</h1>
Here's another unordered list
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

**Though a more flexible alternative** might be to explicitly specify that you want to hide the dashes for the `#TOC`:

```css
ul>li:before {
  content: "\2014";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}

#TOC ul>li:before { display: none; }
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 2em;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  margin-bottom: -0.2em;
}

li {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

ul>li:before {
  content: "\2014";
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}

#TOC ul>li:before { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="TOC" role="doc-toc">
  <h1 id="toctitle">Contents</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>1 Intro</li>
    <li>2 Next
      <ul>
        <li>2.1 Sub</li>
        <li>2.2 MoreSub</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3 More</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1>Introduction</h1>
Here's another unordered list
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```